# Cause of "This app contains code that attempts to bypass android's security protections"

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-security

I have been working on a very benign Android application for a couple months now and all of a sudden I started getting this message on my device when I try to re-install it from IntelliJ.

[image]

My question is, what sort of things would cause Android OS to display this message? If I were to ever release this app, I certainly would not want my users to have to see this before installing.

Comment: What exactly are you using in your app? Take a look at [dangerous permissions table](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html) and see what you're using from those.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> are the only permissions I'm using

Comment: What's the target API? Do you know that API 23+ requires runtime permissions?

Comment: What does the "More details" drop-down tell you? Note that the dialog you are showing is not from standard Android; this must be from some other security feature on your device, either from the device manufacturer or some app that you installed.

Comment: @Vucko, I will verify the API and get back to you

Comment: @CommonsWare, the more details just gives me the option to "install anyway" (I'm paraphrasing since I don't have it up right now).

Comment: @Vucko, I looked up the runtime permissions. I am targeting API 23 but both INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE are not considered dangerous so they do not need to be asked for at runtime.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have been developing an app for some time now an just today I have gotten this message. I don't think that I have installed an OS change, nor added any packages. I don't know what is going on.

Comment: See my answer below, mine error was caused by new version of gradle plugin..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was caused by gradle plugin v2.2.0 (beta version and also RC). When I changed the version back to 2.1.3 problem dissapeared.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
```

Comment: I was using `2.2.0-beta2`. When I upgraded to `2.2.0-rc2`, the warning went away. For those who want to know what the latest version is, [here's a good source](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle).

Comment: Any idea how gradle does this and why ? I had same problem and resolved after I move back to 2.1.3.

Answer (score 2):

I got this message when I tried to grok MVP + Dagger example from this [googlesample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-dagger/todoapp)

After a while I renamed a file [FakeTasksRemoteDataSource.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp-dagger/todoapp/app/src/mock/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/data/FakeTasksRemoteDataSource.java) in my project and Verify Apps fell silent.

So, I think you need to check the file names (and variables) for "stop words", like "fake" etc.

Comment: I use neither Card or Fake. Is there a list of these bad words I can use as a reference?

Comment: I have no any words list. It's just my experience. In my case it worked.
And I think this words is not public information )
You need take a look at your code as a man who build antiviruses program.

Answer (score 2):

Quick Fix while development:

1) Uninstall the current app

2) Build > Rebuild Project

Worked for me. Not sure for others will work or not.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a warning from [Verify Apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2812853?hl=en), which means that your app has been detected as malware. For obvious reasons, there's no detailed explanation of how malware is detected, but given the error message, I would double check anything in your app related to rooting, device admin, changing device security settings, or hacking other apps (including game cheats). If you are still confident it is a false positive, you can try contacting Google to appeal.

Edit: This link has more information. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2992033?hl=en

> Google Play provides an app verification feature that warns users when
>   installing potentially harmful apps from the Internet and third-party
>   markets. In some cases, the app verification feature blocks the
>   installation of apps.
>
> If you believe that your application is incorrectly being warned or
>   blocked by Google Play's app verifier, you can appeal the
>   classification by emailing app-verification-appeals@google.com with:
>
> The application package name. The SHA 256 digest of the application
>   APK. Reason(s) why you believe your application is incorrectly
>   categorized. A screenshot of the warning or blocking screen.

Comment: I am confident it has nothing to do with that. It is a basic app that sends HTTP requests and displays the response data. I will appeal if I cannot find the root cause.